# Export an image with darktable

Tags: darktable

I'm very new to darktable. I can't export (or save) my new modified image. It's version is 1.2.3 (is it outdated?)

Searched for a while; they said [here](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch01s03s03.html.php) that there should be an "export selected" button to the right but I can't find it anywhere.

ctrl+e exports the image directly but I want to choose my format and quality and so...

Where is that button?!?!?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have selected an image and you are in the "lighttable" tab. (I have the German version, so it says "Leuchttisch").

Then the Export field will appear in right bottom corner.

[image: Darktable (German)]

Your Version btw. is a bit outdated. Newest is 1.4.1.
I have installed it via ppa as described on [Darktable Homepage Ubuntu Install](http://www.darktable.org/install/#ubuntu).

Comment: oooh so that's the issue! okay thank you so much :)